# java.net.MalformedURLexception: Protocol not found:

Tags: java, android

Code:

```
String urlAPI = "http://www.domain.com/api.php?msg="+msg+"&mobile="+mobile;
URL url = new URL(urlAPI); HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(); connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String value = bf.readLine();
System.out.println("Result "+value);
```

Logcat:

```
08-13 10:58:45.851 10075-10075/com.example.cyb3rx.smsjungle I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 3.188MB for 281892-byte allocation
08-13 10:58:45.861 10075-10084/com.example.cyb3rx.smsjungle D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 20% free 3234K/4008K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
08-13 10:58:45.871 10075-10972/com.example.cyb3rx.smsjungle W/System.err: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:
```

Comment: `URL url = new URL(urlAPI); HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(); connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); connection.connect(); BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())); String valuee = bf.readLine(); System.out.println("Result "+valuee); `

Comment: 08-13 10:58:45.851 10075-10075/com.example.cyb3rx.smsjungle I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 3.188MB for 281892-byte allocation
08-13 10:58:45.861 10075-10084/com.example.cyb3rx.smsjungle D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 20% free 3234K/4008K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
08-13 10:58:45.871 10075-10972/com.example.cyb3rx.smsjungle W/System.err: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:

Comment: are you able to connect using a browser?

Comment: Don't post code or exceptions in comments. You can see for yourself that they are completely illegible. Edit them into your question.

Comment: @Lino: Yes, It work perfectly in browser

Answer (score 0):

> The query string is composed of a series of field-value pairs. Within
>   each pair, the field name and value are separated by an equals sign,
>   '='. The series of pairs is separated by the ampersand, '&'

try instead

```
String urlAPI = "http://www.domain.com/api.php?msg="+msg+"&mobile="+mobile;
```

Comment: Are you using GET protocol ?

Comment: Yes

`URL url = new URL(urlAPI);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();




BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String valuee = bf.readLine();
System.out.println("Result "+valuee);`

Answer (score 0):

try encoding query parameter with:

URLEncoder.encode("msg="+msg+"&mobile="+mobile, "UTF-8");

so your url will be http://www.domain.com/api.php?msg%3D%20Hello%26mobile%3D%201234567890